# Removing top and bottom space on a tag

Tags: css

is there a way to remove invisible space on top/bottom of a <a> tag.
I have tryed removing paddings, margins and other positions.

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><div class="cog"></div></button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="dop"></div>
        <a href="#">Text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropbtn {
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.3s ease;
    vertical-align: none;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background: #ebebeb;   
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 140px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    left: -53px;
    top: 48px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: #b7b7b7;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
    font-size: 12px; 
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    outline-width: 0px;
}

.show {display:block;}
```

This is how it looks right now -

[image]

This is how it should look like -
[image]

Kinds regards, Ričards.

Comment: Any chance of a jsfiddle example? Thanks

Comment: have you tried adding line-height: 12px?

Comment: @CalvT https://jsfiddle.net/gu0x0juj/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are talking about the line-height property. Try using a low value :

```
line-height: .8em;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no extra padding or margin at the top and bottom of text.

This is normal behaviour of font specification:

[image]

Font-size is defined by **13**, the white spaces are defined by **14** and probably **15** (since you don't have letters with parts below baseline).

You can override this by force line-height lower than font-size. But you must remember that every font has got different **14** in specification and you must choose ratio line-height/font-size (for example 0.8em) by experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Change `line-height` to `10px` or `12px` as you find according to your needs

```css
body {
    background: #e0e0e0;
}
.dropbtn {
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.3s ease;
    vertical-align: none;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background: #ebebeb;   
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 140px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    left: -53px;
    top: 48px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: #b7b7b7;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
    font-size: 12px; 
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    outline-width: 0px;
    line-height: 12px;
}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"><div class="cog"></div></button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="dop"></div>
        <a href="#">Text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```